# Separating out REST API and implementation for Spring web services

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've been using Spring annotations such as `@RestController` and `@RequestMapping` to generate simple services in a Spring Boot Web application.

So I have this trivial example working correctly:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayIt() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Now, I would like to separate out an API library (jar) with only the REST interface and the DTOs. One or more separate libraries would provide the actual implementations of this interface. I can then use the (lightweight) API library on the client-side to generate REST client proxies to talk to any of the implementations.

So... are there any annotations or configuration to mark REST interfaces vs. implementations separately? If not, what is the Spring-y way to achieve this instead of using JAX-RS annotations?

```
@Something1
public class HelloServiceApi {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayIt();
}

@Something2
public class HelloServiceImpl implements HelloServiceApi {
    public String sayIt() {
        return "Hello!";
    }
}
```

Comment: It is confusing what you're asking in the sense that, the Spring WebMVC system is so free form and lacking in any kind of constraint on the way a URL ends up calling a method.  It seems very strange to try to describe what a RESTful Web Service API would look like on the client side with a java Interface.

Comment: @Affe but then perhaps Spring Web MVC is not the right choice for me. I have a well-defined API contract on my services. Are there any Spring-y alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I would advise to have a jar that contains the DTO objects only, without any logic. It then can be used by both the REST server and the client to transfer objects.

The client should not be dependent on the REST war/jar or the logic.

Furthermore, I would try to make sure my controller doesn't hold any logic aside from, maybe, transferring the DTOs into domain model objects which will then be passed to the business logic layer.

Comment: I do want to auto-generate client-side proxies from my API interface. This is why I need only the REST interface without any logic at all. DTOs are of course a part of that REST interface.

Comment: then... what is exactly your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the REST layer should be only responsible for the external API, argument handling, sending to a layer bellow (service layer) and preparing a response.

That being said, you should have your different implementations at the service layer. This allows having the API/REST layer untouched and constant.

The service layer (being providing in different implementations) should respect some common interface that is later injected in the above rest layer.

Have I responded to your question?

Comment: I understand.. and that is how I have it implemented. But I would still like a lightweight "interface" to generate my REST client proxy, for example, using `JAXRSClientFactory.create`. I don't want the client to be dependent on the server-side REST controller.

Comment: But that's the underlying principle of web services, whether rest or soap. To be technology independent. With this being said, why would you have a generated client, instead of a custom one? And why is that client depending on the server tech? I have never used that instruction but it seems to me it should only depend on the external visible rest API within could even be PHP or .net.